# Download the images on Email Client by default

Tags: c#, html-email, email-client

I have noticed one thing whenever user opens any email, by default the email client blocks downloading of images related to that email message. I want to know if there is any way that we can achieve downloading the images by default when the user opens the email message.

The below is the html I have inside the email.

```
<img src="https://Example.aspx?RegID=30932&amp;ID=78" height="1" width="1">
```

More importantly the image is not visible to the user, and the user is list concerned about the presence of it.

Comment: You mean, like those ad trackers people hate? Which is why email clients block images in the first place? Thank goodness, no. It the image isn't part of the email, blocking it is A Very Good Thing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the image is part of the email. But normally the image have to be downloaded by right clicking on it-- like right click--> download pictures. The image will not be visible to the user as the height and width of it is 1px.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé there is no much of work to be shown here, as I'm using an API for sending emails wherein I am just sending html elements as parameters to it.

Comment: "Part of the email" means its part of the MIME payload, not a link. You posted a link to an external message. A tracker no less, the very thing people H-A-T-E. Why do *you* want to know if I read your email? If you wanted a delivery/read receipt, you can set it on the email itself.

Comment: You don't seem to understand what you ask. If *I* (the recipient) don't want to send you a read receipt, what gives you the right to break the law and track me without consent?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If I was not so clear about by requirement, I have updated my question. My concern is I just to know whether it is possible to get the image downloaded by default as soon as the user opens the image.

Comment: The question is very clear. So are the comments. You are trying to use a tracker image, the very thing that email clients try to prevent. Which, by the way, is possibly a privacy violation. If you want email tracking, request a read/delivery receipt

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No that's not what I want. I only want to make the images download by default on the client side. So that the user should not explicitly right click and download them.

Comment: Then don't use links. Include the image in the message. Which means *add its bytes* to the message. If it's just a 1 pixel image it won't increase the size at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice to automatically download images is almost always a user setting in one's email app. These settings cannot be changed by an incoming email message.

As you may know, embedding a clear 1x1 tracking pixel is the standard method for email service provides to track opens in their analytics. Unfortunately, if someone opens an email and does not download this tracking pixel, an ESP cannot track the open in its analytics. Sorry, nature of the business (I deal with this too!).

Comment: answer highly appreciated